# How to know which property is updated?

Tags: java, json, web-services, product

I have a web service that is exposed for the entity.

Now when some one wants to update that entity, let say product as entity and description, they want to update with the help of the web service.
So third party application sending the productid and just the description.  so how would I know that this particular property is updated so that I can set this property to pojo and insert this product in database.

Comment: Be more specific. Preferably, post some mock code.

Comment: Im sorry for that but its more related to architectural question hence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update...
I have found another way of doing the

```
Iterator<?> keys = JsonOject.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext() ) {
                            String key = (String)keys.next();
```

BeanUtils.setProperty(object, key, JsonOject.getString(key));
                                }

By this you can pass key as propertyname and value as described above no need to know which property are coming.Just we have to double check that property should be properly named.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pattern observer ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)). Implement it in the web-service and in the data updater service (by example).

Make your web-service observable and make your dataManager an observer.

In the future, you can add more observer (for an app by example, or another web-service).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compare with its previous version. For example.

You could have a cache of the entity and find in the cache the object by id, after that you need to compare every property. So you can identify the properties that were changed.

If you can't compare againts a cache you will need to compare with your data repository.

I think it's less complicated if your update all the fields.

Comment: Yes that I can do...even I can also tell third party to send the property name of the product which is changed in that way i do not need to set all property but is there any better way?!

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it. I would not recommend that the client sends the fields it changed because it could send wrong information.